# Where is the exact date of start of kaliyug mentioned?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga

The generally held belief is that kaliyuga started around -3102bc. Where is the exact verse or inscription which states this? Also is there any verse which states when dwapara started or treta started? Please quote astronomical reference with planetary positions if any?